# How to set Advanced.EnableCodeExport flag in Dymola through Python?

Tags: python, modelica, dymola

In a workflow, I am trying to automate the process of fmu generation from Dymola using the Python functions in dymola.egg. I was able to achieve this using following function.

```
dymola.translateModelFMU(model, True, 
                              fmiVersion ="2",
                              fmiType ="all");
```

However this generates fmus without binary export (generates license dependent fmus).
I have floating license for binary export available, therefore I would like to checkout and return the binary export license through the script. In order to achieve this, is there a way to set `Advanced.EnableCodeExport = True` through Python?
Is there any other way (other libraries) to achieve this? The goal is to checkout the floating binary export license as needed. I guess with  `dymola.close()` both Dymola and binary export licenses will be returned for others to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dymola.ExecuteCommand()` exists as a fallback solution for everything that can be set from the commands window in Dymola, but is not available in the python interface.

Hence you can set the flag with:

```
dymola.ExecuteCommand("Advanced.EnableCodeExport=true")
```

Note that `true` must be written lower case here (as Modelica and Dymola do, in contrast to python).

Comment: Can `RequestOption()` be used for this as well?

Comment: @Priyanka no, you need to set the flag; RequestOption() alone is not enough. Once you set the flag the option is checked out when needed.